# Copy a file from Windows client to Putty SSH

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer

I want to copy a data from my local windows to my linux server.

The file is in **C:\Users\Test\Desktop\new\foo.txt** and I want to copy it to **xyz@wekroso51.int.bebra.com/home/new/bin**

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Solution 1 --->Try something like this:

pscp -l user1 c:\ftp\picture.jpg slacker1:/home/user1/pics

> As per the [Putty manual](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp):

To send (a) file(s) to a remote server:

pscp [options] source [source...] [user@]host:target

So to copy the local file c:\documents\foo.txt to the server example.com as user fred to the file /tmp/foo you would type:

pscp c:\documents\foo.txt fred@example.com:/tmp/foo

> Solution 2--->Use Filezilla using SFTP instead of putty to transfer files to connect with server.